# CSS code to display image when hovered over

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new at coding. I am having an issue with displaying an image when hovered. The image is in a div. and I am able to hide it but can not figure out what I am doing wrong to show the image when the mouse hovers over the div.

This is for a class assignment and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
#image1 {
 display:none;
}

#image1:hover {
 display:inline;
}

    .box {
 float:left;
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
  margin:10px;
}

#box1 {
 background-color:#51a3a3;
}
```

```html
<section id="work">

<div class="box" div id="box1"> <img id="image1" src="images/photography_lmadesign.png"></div>
<div class="box" div id="box2"><img src="images/cms_lmadesign.png"></div>
<div class="box" div id="box3">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>
<div class="box" div id="box4">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>
<div class="box" div id="box5">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>
<div class="box" div id="box6">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>

</section>
```

Comment: Please ignore the snippet, its the only way I could get my code into the post.

Comment: you have got great answer but for your knowledge..try to read about toggle() and you will be amazed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- On load, you call `#image1 {display:none;}`, so your image cannot be hovered.
- to handle the div mouse move, you mus write `#box1:hover #image1` because `#image1:hover` handle image mouse move

The result is

```css
#image1 {
  display:none;
}

#box1:hover #image1{
  display:inline;
}

.box {
  float:left;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px;
}

#box1 {
  background-color:#51a3a3;
}
```

```html
<section id="work">

  <div class="box" div id="box1"> <img id="image1" src="images/photography_lmadesign.png"></div>
  <div class="box" div id="box2"><img src="images/cms_lmadesign.png"></div>
  <div class="box" div id="box3">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>
  <div class="box" div id="box4">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>
  <div class="box" div id="box5">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>
  <div class="box" div id="box6">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>

</section>
```

Comment: Nice one but it will be great if you will come with live image links rather than static. Thanx

Answer (score 3):

You can't hover on something set to `display: none` , change `#image1:hover` to

`box1:hover > img` to display the image when `#div1` is hovered.

> "The document is rendered as though the element did not exist..."
>
> ---
>
> [MDN Documentation on `display: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values)

**DEMO**

```css
#image1 {
  display: none;
}
#box1:hover > img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#box1 {
  background-color: #51a3a3;
}
```

```html
<section id="work">

  <div class="box" div id="box1">
    <img id="image1" src="http://truestorieswithgill.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/20130915-190532.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="box" div id="box2">
    <img src="images/cms_lmadesign.png">
  </div>
  <div class="box" div id="box3">Content for class "box" Goes Here</div>
  <div class="box" div id="box4">Content for class "box" Goes Here</div>
  <div class="box" div id="box5">Content for class "box" Goes Here</div>
  <div class="box" div id="box6">Content for class "box" Goes Here</div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add hover on div and not on image.

```
#box1:hover #image1 {
    display:inline;
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/9hgay4fj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using `z-index`. Also give a value to your image `alt` attributes.

```css
#image1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

#box1:hover img {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #CCC;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px;
}

#box1 {
    background-color:#51a3a3;
}
```

```html
<section id="work">

    <div class="box" div id="box1"> <img id="image1" src="images/photography_lmadesign.png" alt="Image 1" /></div>
    <div class="box" div id="box2"><img src="images/cms_lmadesign.png" alt="Image 2" /></div>
    <div class="box" div id="box3">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>
    <div class="box" div id="box4">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>
    <div class="box" div id="box5">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>
    <div class="box" div id="box6">Content for  class "box" Goes Here</div>

</section>
```